# YouTube API & Android Support Library incompatibility

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-support-library

**Issue:**

Using the Android Support Library is required to use classes such as DrawerLayout.
This requires that your base activity extends FragmentActivity.

If you need multiple YouTubePlayers in a layout, you should use YouTubePlayerView.
This requires that your base activity extends YouTubeBaseActivity.

Obviously you can't however extend a class from multiple super classes.

**Potential Solutions:**

A) Produce non-support library versions of DrawerLayout etc.

B) Produce a YouTubeBaseFragmentActivity class.

(Perhaps Google's Android and/or YouTube engineers have seen this prob and are working on something?)

**General Comments:**

The design spec for a recent project specified a navigation drawer for navigating the app, while a number of the app screens required multiple YouTube players to be displayed.
This highlighted the basic incompatibility issue.
I can see this issue becoming increasingly common.

Does anyone have an efficient work around to achieve this?
(Apart from just not using drawer navigation and multiple onscreen YouTubePlayers in the same app!)

Comment: How about using youtube fragment in your layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [YouTubePlayerSupportFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) is specifically designed to work with the support library's `FragmentActivity`.

Also note that `DrawerLayout` **does not** require you to use a `FragmentActivity` - any activity will work just fine with it (as it is only a layout).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I tried using YouTubePlayerFragments. Each YouTubePlayerFragments hosts 1 YouTubePlayer. I tried using nested fragments to achieve multiple players on screen, but this resulted in odd behavior with each views progress indicator, flicking between the between the progress of all the players on the screen. I was not aware however, that DrawerLayout could work with standard Fragment class as well as support Fragment class.